# How to find Blank Page in pdf file

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, pdf-parsing

I can not detect blank page in pdf file. I have searched internet for it but could not find a good solution.

> Using Itextsharp I tried with page size, Xobjects. But they do not
>   give exact result.

I tried

```
if(xobjects==null || textcontent==null || size <20 bytes )
  then "blank"
else
 not blank
```

But maximum time it returns wrong answer. I have used **Itextsharp**

The code is below...
I am using **Itextsharp** Librabry

**For xobjects**

```
PdfDictionary xobjects = resourceDic.GetAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
//here resourceDic is PdfDictionary type
//I know that if Xobjects is null then page is blank. But sometimes blank page gives xobjects which is not null.
```

**For contentstream**

```
 RandomAccessFileOrArray f = reader.SafeFile;
 //here reader = new PdfReader(filename);

 byte[] contentBytes = reader.GetPageContent(pageNum, f);
 //I have measured the size of contentbytes but sometimes it gives more than 20 bytes for   blank page
```

**For textcontent**

```
String extractedText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNum, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
  // sometimes blank page give a text more than 20 char length .
```

Comment: What _do_ you get on a page you know to be blank? (Edit this detail into your answer, rather than appending substantial detail in the comments).

Comment: That's a good question now. I don't know the answer, since I've not done any PDF parsing before. Have you analysed those three categories of object to see if empty pages have something in common? For example, what text content actually appears on a blank page?

Comment: Text in blank pages are different from pdf to pdf. I can not find any similarities still now.

Comment: Err, can you provide an example, or do I have to guess?

Comment: I found the text in blank page is 
01 557599 FM.qxd 4/29/04 11.32AM Page ii

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12354/discussion-between-md-kamruzzaman-pallob-and-halfer)

Comment: PDF pages which *seem* to be blank can always contain objects which are not visible (or not printed). The most simple one is the infamous 'white text on white background' example. (You could still highlight the text and copy it though...) A more complex one is a page consisting of different layers, where you by default set to visible (and printing) only an empty layer. -- So... **the only way to reliably discover if a page is *empty* is to 'print' it or 'print it virtually'**. This is what my suggested solution (using Ghostscript) does.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to discover empty pages is this: use a Ghostscript commandline that calls the `bbox` device.

Ghostscript's bbox calculates the coordinates of that minimum rectangle *'bounding box'* which encloses all points of the page where a pixel would be rendered:

```
gs \
  -o /dev/null \
  -sDEVICE=bbox \
   input.pdf
```

On Windows:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o nul ^
  -sDEVICE=bbox ^
   input.pdf
```

Result:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 6.
Page 1
%%BoundingBox: 27 281 548 804
%%HiResBoundingBox: 27.000000 281.000000 547.332031 804.000000
Page 2
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Page 3
%%BoundingBox: 27 302 568 814
%%HiResBoundingBox: 27.949219 302.000000 567.332031 814.000000
Page 4
%%BoundingBox: 27 302 568 814
%%HiResBoundingBox: 27.949219 302.000000 567.332031 814.000000
Page 5
%%BoundingBox: 27 302 568 814
%%HiResBoundingBox: 27.949219 302.000000 567.332031 814.000000
Page 6
%%BoundingBox: 27 302 568 814
%%HiResBoundingBox: 27.949219 302.000000 567.332031 814.000000
```

As you can see, page 2 of my input document was empty.

Comment: I am new with pdf. In command windows I run it but when I run command as a batch file then page number i get as output file nothing else. How can I overcome this problem. @Kurt Pfeifle

Comment: @lazy king: The reason could be this: (1) all lines starting with `Page ` are directed to `stdout`.  (2) all lines starting with `%%BoundingBox: ` or `%%HiResBoundingBox: ` are directed to `stderr`. In the command window the stderr output could possibly be suppressed if you run the command from inside a batch file...

Comment: @lazy king: You could try this `gswin32c.exe -sstdout=%stderr -o nul   -sDEVICE=bbox "input.pdf" 2>output.txt` to re-direct all batch file output to a text file named *output.txt*. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have tried .Trim() on your strings, so I won't suggest that on it's own.

What is the actual contents of the 20+ char length strings in the blank? I suspect it is just new line characters (like what happens when people press <kbd>enter</kbd> 10+ times just to get a new page rather than inserting a page-break), in which case:

```
String extractedText = 
    string.Replace(string.Replace(
        PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNum, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy())
    , Environment.NewLine, ""), "\n", "").Trim();
```

Let us know what the output contents is after this.

Another possibility is that it's blank text with non-breaking spaces and other characters that aren't actually spaces, you'll need to find and replace these manually.. at which point I would instead suggest that you actually just use a regex match for [0-9,a-z,A-Z] and use that to determine if your page is blank or not.

Comment: I do not trim string. I just get the string and show it. I can give you an pdf file which has blank page but it's text is  01 557599 FM.qxd 4/29/04 11.32AM Page ii

Comment: That's likely from hidden fields in the header / footer.. if you can remove header and footers from the document before getting the text from the page that might be a good option.

Comment: Otherwise you might need to render the pages to images and compare if they're blank or not (unless the pages have background images or watermarks or similar).. I look forward to seeing if someone else has a more solid suggestion than that though (if you can't remove the header and footer sections of each page).

Comment: Header or footer remove is not posible. I can only add header or footer.

Comment: After rendering to image how can I check that it is blank? Because I want to do it programmatically not by seeing with my eye. I am trying to know a perfect solution.

Comment: can you read only the non-header/footer content at all? try using http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx it comes in evaluation version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12355/discussion-between-md-kamruzzaman-pallob-and-seph)

Answer (score -1):

There is a wrapper library for C# and VB.NET from a `mupdf c++ library`. You could use it to convert to pages to `bmp` (in diferent formats `tif`, `jpg`, `png`) and check the size of the bitmap.

You should check which is the minimal size with the minimal characters of a page that you will consider as a blank.